# Python Raising Errors within List Comprehension (or a better alternative)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, raiseerror

I have a nested structure read from a json string, that looks similar to the following...

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "type": "test",
    "sub_types": [
      {
        "id": "a",
        "type": "sub-test",
        "name": "test1"
      },
      {
        "id": "b",
        "name": "test2",
        "key_value_pairs": [
          {
            "key": 0,
            "value": "Zero"
          },
          {
            "key": 1,
            "value": "One"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to extract and pivot the data, ready to be inserted in to a database...

```
[
  (1, "b", 0, "Zero"),
  (1, "b", 1, "One")
]
```

I'm doing the following...

```
data_list = [
  (
    type['id'],
    sub_type['id'],
    key_value_pair['key'],
    key_value_pair['value']
  )
  for type in my_parsed_json_array
  if 'sub_types' in type
  for sub_type in type['sub_types']
  if 'key_value_pairs' in sub_type
  for key_value_pair in sub_type['key_value_pairs']
]
```

So far, so good.

What I need to do next, however, is enforce some constraints.  For example...

```
if type['type'] == 'test': raise ValueError('[test] types can not contain key_value_pairs.')
```

But I can't put that in to the comprehension.  And I don't want to resort to loops.  My best thought so far is...

```
def make_row(type, sub_type, key_value_pair):
    if type['type'] == 'test': raise ValueError('sub-types of a [test] type can not contain key_value_pairs.')
    return (
        type['id'],
        sub_type['id'],
        key_value_pair['key'],
        key_value_pair['value']
    )

data_list = [
  make_row(
    type,
    sub_type,
    key_value_pair
  )
  for type in my_parsed_json_array
  if 'sub_types' in type
  for sub_type in type['sub_types']
  if 'key_value_pairs' in sub_type
  for key_value_pair in sub_type['key_value_pairs']
]
```

That works, but it will make the check for each and every key_value_pair, which feels redundant.  *(Each set of key value pairs could have thousands of pairs, and the check only needs to be made once to know that they're all fine.)*

Also, there will be other rules similar to this, that apply at different levels of the hierarchy.  Such as "test" types can only contain "sub_test" sub_types.

What are the options other than those above?

- More elegant?
- More extensible?
- More performant?
- More "Pythonic"?

Comment: Try codereview.SE for this sort of thing. I would vote to close, but the migration options are incredibly limited (and IMHO a bizarre selection).

Comment: Use loops. Comprehensions with side effects are annoying. Python is not lisp.

Comment: You should read about how to validate your `json` data and specify explicit schema constraints with
[JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/) This library has It's python implementation here:
[jsonschema package](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: @MihaiAndrei They are building a list because they *need* a list, this is not a side effect. The only thing that could arguably taken out the comprehension is the error handling, which could be performed once before the iteration starts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about how to validate your `json` data and specify explicit schema constraints with
[JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/)
This library allows you to set keys which are required, specify default values, add type validation, etc.

This library has It's python implementation here:
[jsonschema package](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

**EXAMPLE:**

```
from jsonschema import Draft6Validator

schema = {
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/schema#",

    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {"type": "string"},
        "email": {"type": "string"},
    },
    "required": ["email"]
}
Draft6Validator.check_schema(schema)
```

Comment: Yes, this is probably the "proper" approach, instead of trying to combine transformation and validation in to a single pass of the data structure. (I tend to try to micro-optimise where I don't need to.)

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a plain loop, but you can add it to the first conditional check, if you put the statement into a function:

```
def type_check(type):
    if type['type'] == 'test':
        raise ValueError('sub-types of a [test] type can not contain key_value_pairs.')
    return True


data_list = [
  (
    type['id'],
    sub_type['id'],
    key_value_pair['key'],
    key_value_pair['value']
  )
  for type in my_parsed_json_array
  if 'sub_types' in type
  for sub_type in type['sub_types']
  if  'key_value_pairs' in sub_type and type_check(type)
  for key_value_pair in sub_type['key_value_pairs']
]
```

Comment: this will call the test type for each line in the json.

Comment: @BearBrown  You mean each dict in the outer list? Yes, I thought that was the point.

Comment: yes i think this way, but your solution should help the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You could try an architecture along the lines of

```
def validate_top(obj):
    if obj['type'] in BAD_TYPES:
        raise ValueError("oof")
    elif obj['type'] not in IRRELEVANT_TYPES: # actually need to include this
        yield obj

def validate_middle(obj):
    # similarly for the next nested level of data

# and so on

[
    make_row(r)
    for t in validate_top(my_json)
    for m in validate_middle(t)
    # etc...
    for r in validate_last(whatever)
]
```

The general pattern I have here is using generators (functions, not expressions) to *process* the data, and then comprehensions to *collect* it.

In simpler cases, where it isn't worthwhile to separate out multiple levels of processing (or they don't naturally exist), you can still write a single generator and just do something like `list(generator(source))`. This is, in my mind, still cleaner than using an ordinary function and building the list manually - it still separates 'processing' vs 'collecting' concerns.

Comment: I like, other than one caveat.  `validate_last()` needs to be supplied with `t` in order to enforce the constraint in my example.  *(`'test'` types are fine, it's `key_value_pairs`, the bottom level, that are constrained to being "illegal" when `t['type'] == 'test'`...)*